# Reading iBeacon Data using HC-05 bluetooth module

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I have bought a HC-05 bluetooth module for Arduino.

My requirement is to read data transmitted from iBeacon, is it possible using HC-05 or I have to shift to HM-10?

Comment: did you come up with a plan? Because I am dealing with the same issue, would love to see an answer without having to post the same question.

Answer (score 2):

The HC-05 doesn't support BLE, which is used for iBeacons.

Comment: Is it possible to read ibeacon data with Arduino using HM-10 module? If not then what's the best option?

Comment: Probably yes. But I'm not into BT.